# How to export new generic function for new S3 class?

Tags: r, package, r-s3

I define a new function `work_with_myS3` that is supposed to work with my new S3 class `myS3`:

```
work_with_myS3 = function (x) {
   UseMethod("work_with_myS3", x)
}

work_with_myS3.myS3 = function(x) {
   some code
}
```

When I source this in my normal R session (I'm using RStudio), it behaves exactly as expected. When I feed it an `myS3` object, it works; when I feed it something strange, it throws an error:

```
> work_with_myS3(123)
Error in UseMethod("work_with_myS3", x) : 
  no applicable method for 'work_with_myS3' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
```

However, when I include this in my package, build it, reload it and try to call it:

```
Error: could not find function "work_with_myS3"
```

Help page works fine though, calling `?work_with_myS3`. This is how I document it by `devtools::document()`:

```
#' Do stuff with myS3
#'
#' What it does
#' @import dplyr
#' @param x object of class myS3
#' @method work_with_myS3 myS3
#' @export
```

There is also an entry in the namespace:

```
S3method(work_with_myS3,myS3)
```

Why is this, and how to make the function available in the package? I suspect I'm making some trivial mistake.

Comment: Define a default method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `work_with_myS3` with an object of class `myS3` the `UseMethod` function looks for:

1. `work_with_myS3.myS3` or
2. `work_with_myS3.default`

Therefore you need to export `work_with_myS3.myS3`, so

```
#' @export
work_with_myS3.myS3 = function(x) {
  ## do stuff
}
```

Alternatively, you could define a `default` method and export that.

Comment: So basically, it's about the placement of the @export tag, right?